# Why does this local ArrayList change?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this weird bug that I cannot fix. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```
ArrayList<Choices> newSecurityChoicesList =
    securityChoicesController.getChoicesList();
System.out.println("first-" + newSecurityChoicesList.size());
securityQuestion.getChoices().clear();
System.out.println("second-" + newSecurityChoicesList.size());
```

Some explanation:

I created this `newSecurityChoicesList` `ArrayList`. It is a local variable in a method.
The first system print out gives me a result of 2.

Why does the second print out give me a result of 0?

Of course it is because of the `securityQuestion.getChoices().clear();` method.
But why can a method change a local variable in a method? This method is only called once at the very end of the application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And 83.62% of all statistics are made up on the spot.

Comment: Why downvote a legitimate beginner's question?  Understanding the difference between "by reference" and "by value" is a critical part of any programmer's education.

Comment: @AdamLiss, you're right. My research shows the percentage of false BUGs is actually higher. :)

Comment: I think that the down-votes are coming because he mentions (perhaps unintentionally) that he thinks that the bug is in Java and not in his understanding of Java. He may want to re-word his original question to eliminate this possible interpretation of it. Note that I up-voted the question.

Comment: You clear the Object's list, so it's size is reduced to 0. I can't really understand what's your point here.

Also, @KenWhite what is this attitude against starters?

Comment: Try printing `securityChoicesController.getChoicesList()` and `newSecurityChoicesList`

Comment: @Ismet, what attitude? My point (made with a :), if you'll notice) was that almost everything posted as a BUG is a mistake made by the programmer. There was no *attitude* intended. What's with the personal attack?

Comment: It's obvious that ":)" is sarcastic. There's no point in making jokes of starters, we're all here to help and get helped.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan, if you'll look at people's reps before accusing them of not being helpful, you might learn something. I've answered more than one question here, and provided lots of help to new programmers. You might lighten up and get a little bit of a sense of humor. :-) (Notice the smile - it's not sarcasm, in case you're not sure.) You might also note I made a helpful suggestion to you earlier as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are dealing with a reference variable and changing the property of the object it refers to. So while the method's local variable will be local, it will be referring to the object that was passed in to the method. Again, this is not a bug in Java, but a problem with your understanding about reference variables.

If you don't want to change the state of the ArrayList passed into the method, then make a deep copy of it in the method before working with it. In other words, you'll want to create a new ArrayList and then iterate through the parameter ArrayList, making copies of each item in the original list before adding it to the new list.

Comment: Or `getChoices` could wrap the list with [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList\(java.util.List\)) before returning it.

Comment: Oh, i see what you mean. So your saying that securityChoicesController.getChoicesList(); was modified during the process therefore newSecurityChoicesList was only a reference to the object?.. Thanks very much.

Comment: @TheJAVANoob: yes, the newXXX variable refers to the original object. Either do what DavidHarkness suggests or in the `getChoicesList()` method, return a deep copy of the List.

Answer (score 1):

Is is because the `ArrayList<Choice>` is held by reference, thus you are modifiying the same object via two references -- one as your local variable and the other in the `securityQuestion` object